# Giving the position when quoting ebook without page count?

Tags: citations, citation-style

My question is referring to APA citation and specifically if it is accepted to provide the position a quote from a Kindle ebook can be found at. The ebook in question does not provide page numbers. In my own notes I always put down the position. Now I know that the "official" recommendation is to provide chapter, section and paragraph. The quotes are indirect and this means that I can't search for them and add this info easily. But giving a position still makes it possible to understand the context of what I'm referring to. Would you say it's down to the prof or out of question to give a position?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using APA style guide just stick to what they say - they have solved the problem so that you don't have to spend time thinking on it.

Personally in all of my papers I've always resorted to giving chapter and paragraph where available and never gave the location number - in addition to style guidelines arguments some people find location designation confusing.